# mariadb 10.2 is not available in rhel 7 repo

Tags: redhat, mariadb

I tried to install mariadb 10.2 using default red hat 7 repository. but as it seems there only available upto mariadb 10.1. when I googled, lot of articles were there and all are saying "in order to install MariaDB 10.2 you have to add MariaDB repositories". but my concern here is MariaDB does not guarantee for the security patches and bug fixes, even they said that they will be providing the support for five years since the day of any particular version is released. But as per my understanding if redhat default repository had this MariaDB 10.2, then red hat will take care of the maintenance until the corresponding redhat os version is deprecated. So anyone knows whether RedHat is gonna add the MariaDB 10.2 into their repo or not? please correct me if I'm wrong in my statement.
thanks in advance

Comment: Probably never on RHEL 7, that would probably be a breach of interface stability. When available [RHEL 8 will directly jump to MariaDB 10.3](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8-beta/html-single/8.0_beta_release_notes/#web_servers_databases_dynamic_languages).

Answer (score 3):

As per MariaDB documentation, you can do that with the following steps:

1. Create a file called `mariadb.repo` under the path `/etc/yum.repos.d/`
2. Paste the following inside:

   > [mariadb]
   >   name = MariaDB
   >   baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.2/rhel7-amd64
   >   gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
   >   gpgcheck=1
3. Proceed with the installation `yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client`

Please refer to the following link for more info:

https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=digitalocean-nyc&distro=RedHat&distro_release=rhel7-amd64--rhel7&version=10.2

I hope this helps.